# angular js multiple filter with one filter ending as 'as'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically, i want to achieve multiple filter with the first filter being the search filter, then the second filter will be checking whether it is favorite.

```
ng-repeat-start="customer in vm.model.customers =  (arr | filter:vm.searchCustomer | filter:{favorite: 0} as filteredCustomer)"
```

if i do the filter one by one, basically they work.
But if i combine it, it triggers up error which state that :

```
alias 'filteredCustomer' is invalid --- must be a valid JS identifier which is not a reserved name.
```

What is the issue here, and how do i resolve it?
Thank you

Comment: Believe you shouldn't have = and as in one line might also try extra parens around the set of filters before the as.

Comment: extra parens? Can you explain what do you mean? Thank you. ^^ @shaunhusain

Comment: `ng-repeat-start="customer in vm.model.customers =  ( (arr | filter:vm.searchCustomer | filter:{favorite: 0} ) as filteredCustomer)"` something like this is what I'm thinking, sometimes the parser has troubles that can be solved by extra parenthesis showing it what to process first.